# Questions about ”operator=” and ”operator[]”

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a question about the code below.

Why is it possible to run `const auto& vec1 = vec;` successfully even though `my_vector& operator=(const my_vector&) = delete` is defined?

Secondly, why is the `&`, `&&` at the end of `operator[]` necessary? If I remove them, I get an error.

I understand that the `&` after the operator is a reference to the class itself.
Then I grasp that the ones without `const` are for writing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<vector>

template<typename T, typename Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class my_vector
{
  std::vector<T, Alloc> vec;

public:
  my_vector(const my_vector&);
  my_vector& operator=(const my_vector&) = delete;
  my_vector(std::initializer_list<T> init) : vec{init} {}
  T& operator[](std::size_t n) & { std::cout<<"&"<<std::endl; return vec[n]; }
  const T& operator[](std::size_t n) const& { std::cout<<"const &"<<std::endl;  return vec[n]; }
  T operator[](std::size_t n)  && noexcept {std::cout<<"move"<<std::endl; return std::move(vec[n]); } 
};

int main()
{
    my_vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
    
    const auto& vec1 = vec;
    vec[0] = 2; //case1 &
    std::cout<<vec1[0]<<std::endl;
    //vec1[0] = 1; const error
    int tmp1 = vec1[0] ; //case2 const&
    auto&& vec5 = my_vector<int>{1, 2, 3}[0]; //case3 move
}
```

Comment: First of all even though you use the `=`, when you define variables it's *initialization* (construction) and not assignment. Secondly, you define a *reference* not a copy of `vec`, so even deleting the copy-constructor wouldn't have made a difference.

Comment: `const auto& vec1 = vec` creates a reference that is an alias of `vec`.      It doesn't attempt to call `vec`s assignment operator (or any other operation, for that matter), so deleting the assignment operator does not affect it.

Comment: The `&` and `&&` adornment on `operator[]()` result in overloading based on whether the object it is being called on is an lvalue or rvalue respectively.   Only strictly necessary if it is necessary to have different behaviours if the `operator[]()` is being called on a vector that is an lvalue or rvalue respectively.    Your example (printing a different string based on whether the vector is lvalue or rvalue, but not otherwise doing anything substantially different) is a rather weak example - for illustrative purposes only.

Comment: Thanks to your points, I now understand.
Thank you very much.